# Formula natural frequency double wall

Tags: vibration, sound-isolation

I started with a book (pdf see here: https://www.pdhonline.com/courses/m104/m104_new.htm)

In this book there is the following formulla found
$$f_0 = 170 / \sqrt{M_1 * t  / (1 + M_1 / M_2)}$$.
The page i refereing to is 4-2 (added below) but can also be found on this link(called page 28) 
http://buildingcriteria2.tpub.com/ufc_3_450_01/ufc_3_450_010032.htm
For text related to this figure see page 27 of the same link.
[image: Figure 4-2 from the link]

I assume the situation it decibes is showed in situation B of figure 4-3
[image: Figure 4-3 find on page 29]

It is not a difficult formula but still i have some difficulties with it... The for here most importand one is as follows. When try to convert the formula to metric i run into a unit problem...
So the unit version is as follows. $$f_0[1 / s] =  170[?] /  \sqrt{[lb / ft^2] * ([ft] / 12) / (1 + [lb / ft^2] / [lb/ft^2] )}$$ 
With 
$(1 + [lb / ft^2] / [lb/ft^2]) = [-]$ and $[lb / ft^2] * ([ft] / 12) = [lb / (ft * 12)]$ resulting $1/[sec]  = 170[?] / \sqrt{[lb / ft]}$ (i ignore the factor $1/12$ for now).
This would mean the unit (of the 170) of the numerator should be $\sqrt{[lb/ft]} /s$ while i would expect that it should be related to the speed of sound(and thus in $ft/sec$. The denumerator is would have $ft$ as unit).

So my question is as this:
Where is this formula come from how is this formula build up. AND maybe a pointer to a paper where this formula comes from.

Comment: What do you mean by double wall? What are you referring to?

Comment: I assumed theformula and the text of the [original link](http://buildingcriteria2.tpub.com/ufc_3_450_01/ufc_3_450_010032.htm) describing the situation of [figure on the next page](http://buildingcriteria2.tpub.com/ufc_3_450_01/ufc_3_450_010033im.jpg).
Edit i figured out that i can link to single images... i try to insert them in the original text